# How to add connection string "credentials" dynamically from template in NLOG

Tags: .net, web-config, config, nlog

I'm trying to pull up database connection string credentials from template config file for my Nlog connection string, I tried doing it somehow it's not working, any suggestions would appreciate

```
 <target name="database" connectionString=":ConnectionStringSTR" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="false" useTransactions="true" commandType="Text" dbProvider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"
      commandText="insert into LOG (LogName,LogDetails) values (:LogName,:LogDetails)">

        <parameter name="LogName" layout="${event-context:item=LogName}" />
        <parameter name="LogDetails" layout="${event-context:item=LogDetails}" />
  </target>
```

Below under resource tag I created a credential variable which will generate connection string with respective username and password

```
<Properties>
              <Property Name="ConnectionStringSTR" Value="Data Source=ABCD100;User Id=NLOGUSER;Password=NLOG12345;Persist Security Info=false"/>
              <Property Name="ConnectionTimeout" Value="15"/>
            </Properties>
```

This is not working as records are not getting inserted in DB.
How to configure this values - ***connectionString=":ConnectionStringSTR"***

Comment: What is the filename that contains the `<Property Name="ConnectionStringSTR" .. />` ? I recommend you make use of https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppSetting-Layout-Renderer or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Comment: Or are you trying to do XML-transformation ? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438204/config-transformation-on-nlog-does-not-work